# Where do I get the iPhone SDK from

Tags: ios, webdriver

I am trying to setup some WebDriver tests to run on an iPad and am having a heck of a time.

The instructions from Selenium say:
For now, you will need the full set of development tools from apple to install on your device.

Install the iphone SDK and configure your build environment as described above. You will also need a provisioning profile from Apple to be installed and configured for your device.

Where do I get the iPhone SDK from to put onto the device? I cannot find them anywhere on the App store on the device.

Comment: The SDK is not an iOS package. It's a Mac package.

Comment: so how do I get it onto the device as the instructions state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Mac, you can download XCode 4 which contains everything you will need to develop for the iPhone including:

-IDE
-Performance Analysis
-iOS SDK
-OSX SDK

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

To load an app on your device, you will need to sign up as a developer to access the *Provisioning Portal*. An annual fee of $99 is required to become a developer which includes distribution on the App Store among other things.